# Vector reflections

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

For a vector $\vec{v}$, let $\vec{r}$ be the reflection of $\vec{v}$ over the line
$\vec{x} = t \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$
[image]

There exists a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\vec{R}$ such that
$\vec{r} = \vec{R} \vec{v}$
for all 2-dimensional vectors $\vec{v}$. Find $\vec{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You just need to figure out how a basis would be transformed under this operation. So what are some vectors whose reflections should be easy to figure out geometrically?  How about a vector *on* the line, for instance $\pmatrix{2\\ -1}$, and one *orthogonal* to the line, for instance $\pmatrix{1\\ 2}$.  Can you figure out where these two vectors will be mapped under this reflection?  Can you then figure out how to build a matrix from this info?

Answer (score 1):

Hint... The matrix which reflects in the line $y=x(\tan\theta)$ is $$\left(\begin{matrix}\cos 2\theta & \sin 2\theta \\ \sin 2\theta & -\cos 2\theta\end{matrix}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $q=\langle2, -1\rangle$ and let $u=\frac{q}{|q|}=\langle\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\rangle.$

If $U=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\end{bmatrix}$, then the projection onto the line is given by $P=UU^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{4}{5}&-\frac{2}{5}\\-\frac{2}{5}&\frac{1}{5}\end{bmatrix}$,

so $r+v=2Pv\implies R=2P-I=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{5}&-\frac{4}{5}\\-\frac{4}{5}&-\frac{3}{5}\end{bmatrix}$